# Write a function filterLongWords() that finds and displays all words that are longer than a given integer i in C#

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming I have this exercise where I have to Write a function filterLongWords() that finds and displays all words that are longer than a given integer i in a list that has been passed in as an argument and I cant display the words more than once and I don't know how to write it if any one here could tell me how or tell me a website I can go to for help that would be ok too.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint for u....

1. Pass a string array to that `List<string> filterLongWords(string[] words)` function.
2. Instantiate a list that you will return at the end.
3. Implement a foreach loop that iterates that array.
4. Now you look at the length of that current iterated word and if it doesn't fit your length put it in your instantiated list.
5. Return your instantiated list or convert it to an array and return that.

I won't code it for you - it's just a hint.

Comment: I would appreciate it, when you close this thread by accepting one possible answer to help the others, when they are finding this. This is the main goal of this community.